# A cut in directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $(S,T)$ be a cut in a graph $G$. What is the cut set? Is it the set of all edges from $S$ to $T$ or does it include the edges from $T$ to $S$?

Answer (score 4):

In a directed graph $G=(V,A)$ the a cut is defined as the set of *outgoing* arcs, i.e. the set of arcs whose tail is in $S$ and whose head is in $T$, where $S$ denotes the node-set containing the source $s$ and $T$ denotes the node-set containing the sink $t$.

In undirected graph you are given edges, not arcs. That's why there can be made no distinction between outgoing and incoming arcs. That's why in this case the cut set consists of all edges with one point in $S$ and the other point in $T$.

Answer (score 2):

From [Cut (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29):

Any cut determines a cut-set, the set of edges that have one endpoint in each subset of the partition.

By the way, nobody cares about the names $S$ and $T$ in a cut. You can exchange those sets and your cut would still be a cut. Therefore it doesn't make sense to talk only about edges from $S$ to $T$ but not from $T$ to $S$.

Comment: what about s-t cut in a network, with a source s and a sink t?

Comment: @hagit: If necessary to talk about directed graphs, you should edit your Question or (perhaps preferably, since this already has an upvoted answer) post a new Question about that.